# flutter pubspec.yaml - select package version from git

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, dart-packages

I need get package form github
I know how to do it

```
dart_vlc:
dart_vlc_ffi:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/alexmercerind/dart_vlc.git
      path: ffi
      ref: master
```

**But** my problem
it's get old version .. I need latest version

and I have one questions

how I can select version from tags (like use dart_vlc v0.1.8 from github)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the latest version of `dart_vlc`.

Mention dependencies as follows in your `pubspec.yaml` to use the GitHub version of the `dart_vlc` in your Flutter project.

```yaml
dependencies:
  dart_vlc:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/alexmercerind/dart_vlc.git
      ref: master

dependency_overrides:
  dart_vlc_ffi:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/alexmercerind/dart_vlc.git
      ref: master
      path: ffi
```